# mkdir with subfolders working in terminal but not from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mkdir

I wanted to create some folders with subfolders and have this python3 script that would read a csv file and create directories for me.

```
from subprocess import call
import csv

def csv_dict_reader(file_obj):
    """
    Read a CSV file using csv.DictReader
    """
    reader = csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        sanitized_name = line["course"].replace(" ", "-").lower()

        command = 'mkdir -p ' + sanitized_name + '/week_{1..'+ line["week"] +'}/{slides,exercise,assignment}'
        call(command)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("courses.csv") as f_obj:
        csv_dict_reader(f_obj)
```

I was expecting that it executes commands of this sort

```
mkdir -p algorithmic-toolbox/week_{1..6}/{slides,exercise,assignment}
```

which works fine from the terminal and creates a folder called `algorithmic-toolbox` with 6 folders from `week1 to week6` and then each folder contains `slides, exercises and assignment` folders.

A sample csv would be like this:

```
course,week
Algorithmic Toolbox,6
Data Structures,4
Algorithms on Graphs,5
```

I am getting this error when I run the python script.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "course-folder.py", line 18, in <module>
    csv_dict_reader(f_obj)
  File "course-folder.py", line 13, in csv_dict_reader
    call(command)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 267, in call
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mkdir -p algorithmic-toolbox/week_{1..6}/{slides,exercise,assignment}': 'mkdir -p algorithmic-toolbox/week_{1..6}/{slides,exercise,assignment}'
```

Not sure why it says `FilenotFoundError` when I am creating directories with `-p` which is supposed to create the parent directories if they don't exist.

Comment: Try `shell=True`?

Comment: why call subprocess and not [`os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=mkdir#os.makedirs) (or [`pathlib.Path.mkdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html?highlight=pathlib#pathlib.Path.mkdir))?

Comment: It's a duplicate, but to realize that I never knew what actual question to ask ("parameter expansion" might have been the key). And using subprocess just because it was the first solution I came to. Not being an expert on either python or shell, I chose the first convenient method, no particular reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mkdir -p algorithmic-toolbox/week_{1..6}/{slides,exercise,assignment}
```

I believe parameter expansion used in the above command will not work without passing the `shell=True` argument to [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). This way Python will execute the command in an intermediate shell process.

If you want your script to be platform independent you could instead use `os.mkdir` and handle the logic in Python.